# Sort object's properties by value and keep values

Tags: javascript

I have created an array of food names that has duplicate data. By using:

```
listFoodnames.forEach(x => {
  counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) + 1;
});
```

I can count how many times each item exists in the array.

Using:

```
Object.keys(counts).sort((a, b) => counts[b]-counts[a])
```

I can sort the items' count from greatest to lowest, however, I lose the actual count that I'd like to keep.

How can I solve this?

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  var listFoodnames = ["Batteries", "Bread", "Milk", "Bread", "Milk", "Milk"]
  var counts = {};

  listFoodnames.forEach(x => {
    counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) + 1;
  });

  console.log(counts) //LOGS EACH ITEM AS PROPERTY AND OCCURRENCES AS VALUE
  
  var sortedCounts = Object.keys(counts).sort((a, b) => counts[b]-counts[a])
  
  console.log(sortedCounts) //LOSES VALUES
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think dictionaries are not ordered. You can keep another array of sorted values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, object properties are not guaranteed to be ordered, per the spec. You might try using an array of objects instead.

Also note that `reduce` is more appropriate than `forEach` when you're combining items in an array into a single object.

```js
const listFoodnames = ["Batteries", "Bread", "Milk", "Bread", "Milk", "Milk"];
const counts =
  Object.values(
    listFoodnames.reduce((a, foodName) => {
      if (!a[foodName]) a[foodName] = { foodName, count: 0 };
      a[foodName].count++;
      return a;
    }, {})
  );
counts.sort((a, b) => a.count - b.count);
console.log(counts);
```

Comment: `object properties are not guaranteed to be ordered, per the spec.`  With ES6, this has changed.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
var sortedCounts = Object.keys(counts).sort((a, b) => counts[b] - counts[a]);
```

use

```
var sortedCounts = Object.entries(counts).sort(([keyA, a], [keyB, b]) => b - a);
```

Next, you could map each `[key, value]` entry to a new object:

```
console.log(sortedCounts.map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value})));
```

The result will look like this:

```
[
  {
    "Milk": 3
  },
  {
    "Bread": 2
  },
  {
    "Batteries": 1
  }
]
```

Note, that it is impossible to get something like

```
{
  "Milk": 3,
  "Bread": 2,
  "Batteries": 1
}
```

to work, since object properties do not have an order.

Comment: `Note, that it is impossible to get something like`,  With ES6, this is not the case now,..

Answer (score 1):

Everyone who has replied has incorrectly said -> `dictionaries are not ordered`

This is actually wrong, ES6 made the spec change, and have said dictionary's are ordered.  Although before ES6 order was not specified, most browser did even then have an order.  The order by the way is insertion order.  The order will also work when serialized, eg. JSON.parse / JSON.stringify.

So using this knowledge we can make the result into the format your after, a sorted object.

example below.

```js
var listFoodnames = ["Batteries", "Bread", "Milk", "Bread", "Milk", "Milk"]
var counts = {};

listFoodnames.forEach(x => {
  counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) + 1;
});

console.log(counts) //LOGS EACH ITEM AS PROPERTY AND OCCURRENCES AS VALUE

const sortedCount = 
  Object.entries(counts).sort((a,b) => b[1] - a[1]).
  reduce((a,v) => (a[v[0]] = v[1], a), {});

console.log(sortedCount);
```